# How to block the htaccess login dialog box in pop-up ads?

Tags: firefox, browser, htaccess

Nowadays some websites won't let you use their platform without disabling your adblocker.

I was recently exposed to a **new type of pop-up ad** : In order to avoid being closed quickly by the user, a **htaccess login dialog box is displayed**, while a video or any other sound-based ad is playing in the background.

This kind of pop-up windows are particularly difficult to close, as the login dialog is opening again and again each time you click the cancel button (at least on Firefox).

I didn't investigate further as how it is actually done, but I guess that the web page loads its audio/video element then queries a resource which is protected by htaccess.

1. Is there a way to block globally the htaccess login box ?
2. If yes, is it possible to filter which websites (domain) are allowed, so I can still connect to my private/work protected domains ?

**Note** : The login box is indeed an htaccess login dialog (and not only a regular javascript `alert()`) as the problematic pop-up also displays a js `alert()`.

Comment: What version of FIrefox are you using?  According to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1312243 the issue may have been addressed in Firefox 52.

Comment: Firefox 52.0.2 (64-bit)/ Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Edit : Realized that the problem occurs on my desktop, I will update the comment with its FF version later. Thanks for the link, that's exactly the issue I'm encountering !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to FCTW's comment, the issue was resolved in Firefox 52 :
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1312243

The patch protects against abuse auth prompts :

> Note that this fixes only a case when a page contains an iframe that
>   1) asks for auth 2) is reloaded by the top level page on and on.  If
>   such the page would reload itself (not just the iframe), the patch
>   would not help.